# update the state of a component from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update icon of component from another component. whenever I clicked on a playlist music start playing and icon should be change to pause instead of play but I don't know how I can update the state of a component from another component.

 **PlayList Component -** 
playlist and musics are in this component

```
class PlayList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const playMusic = () => {
            musics.forEach(e => e.pause());
            musics[this.props.arr].play();
            musics[this.props.arr].currentTime = 0;
            nowPlaying = this.props.arr;
            clickedOnMusic = 'clicked';
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <Card>
                    <CardActionArea onClick={playMusic} />
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
}
```

**BottomAppBar Component -** 
icons and some function to playing music are here

```
class BottomAppBar extends React.Component {
    state = {
        displayPlay: 'none',
        displayPause: '',
        displayVolume: '',
        displayMute: 'none'
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <IconButton onClick={handleChangePlay} style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                <PauseCircleOutlineRoundedIcon
                    style={{ fontSize: 46, display: this.state.displayPlay }}
                />
                <PlayCircleOutlineIcon
                    style={{ fontSize: 46, display: this.state.displayPause }}
                />
      )
}
```

thank you very much for reading !

Comment: You can use redux to do that or you can use react hooks

Comment: yeah but I write a lot of code. refactoring to redux is not possible here but you're right

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a container and maintain their states over there.
Ex:

```
<Parent>
   <PlayList/>
   <BottomAppBar />
</Parent>
```

Comment: can you please explain more

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context api, any ascendent of `PlayerLogic` can access whatever you put in the context with `React.useContext` and will be re rendered when values in the Context change.

```js
const PlayerContext = React.createContext();
const PlayerLogic = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    playing: false,
  });
  const setPlaying = React.useCallback(
    val =>
      setState(current => ({ ...current, playing: val })),
    []
  );
  const pause = React.useCallback(() => setPlaying(false), [
    setPlaying,
  ]);
  const play = React.useCallback(() => setPlaying(true), [
    setPlaying,
  ]);
  return (
    <PlayerContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        pause,
        play,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </PlayerContext.Provider>
  );
};
const ComponentOne = () => {
  const {
    pause,
    play,
    state: { playing },
  } = React.useContext(PlayerContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {playing ? (
        <button onClick={pause}>pause</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={play}>play</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
class ComponentTwo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.context.state.playing
      ? 'now playing'
      : 'nothig is playing';
  }
}
ComponentTwo.contextType = PlayerContext;
const A = () => <B />;
const B = () => <C />;
const C = () => {
  const {
    state: { playing },
  } = React.useContext(PlayerContext);
  return `In component C, is playing ${JSON.stringify(
    playing
  )}`;
};
const App = () => (
  <PlayerLogic>
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
    <div>
      <A />
    </div>
  </PlayerLogic>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not using hooks and I want to save the core of program

Comment: @TuR1NG Changed ComponentTwo to a class. `I want to save the core of program` not sure what you mean, currently the context has only 3 properties that can easily be set.